# How to concatenate several strings and variables in Yaml?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I need to do something like this:

```
domain: &domain example.com
ip: &ip 1.2.3.4
Address4: v=spf1 include:*domain ip4:*ip -all
```

I tried this but didn't work, it says there's a syntax error:

```
Address4: 'v=spf1 include:'*domain' ip4:'*ip' -all'
```

The implementation (I'm using these files in Ansible) seems to support concatenation, for example this works fine:

```
Address2: http://*domain # actually this doesn't work, I don't remember the exact example
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I don't exactly get why you're trying to concatinate in YAML, since Ansible uses [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) as a templating engine:

Defining variables in a vars file for Ansible (in YAML):

```
domain: example.com
ip: 1.2.3.4
```

Referencing variables (still in YAML):

```
Address4: v=spf1 include:{{ domain }} ip4:{{ ip }} -all
```

When you use the Address4 variable in the template module (I assume), it works the same way.